# How to add tab space before QAction buttons in QMainToolBar

Tags: qt, toolbar, qmainwindow

How can I add space before `QAction` icons.Like this image.I set style-sheet for `mainToolBar`  like this `spacing:10px;` But I need to add tab space before icon 1.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make placeholder widget and use *QToolBar::insertWidget*  for insert that widget.
UPD: Example of code

```
QWidget* placeholder = new QWidget( this );
ui->toolBar->insertWidget( new QAction( this ), placeholder );
placeholder->setWidth(100);
```

Comment: I'm not clear your answer.can you please tell me how can I do it.can you give me a sample

Comment: {
 QWidget* placeholder = new QWidget( this );
 ui->toolBar->insertWidget( new QAction( this ), placeholder );
 placeholder->setWidth(100);
}

Comment: Just remove extra 's' in method name. Right name is 'QToolBar::addAction'

Comment: `setWidth()` is not member of `QWidget` .. use   `placeholder->setMinimumWidth(100);`